# iPad Air strange Mask + animation behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios7

we realized an App some time ago which does an animation behind a masked view:

```
UIBezierPath *myBezierPath = myVectorDrawing.bezier;


CAShapeLayer *myShapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
myShapeLayer.path = myBezierPath.CGPath;

debugLog(@"wize: height%f width%f",myShapeLayer.frame.size.height, myShapeLayer.frame.size.width);

CAShapeLayer *maskWithHole = [CAShapeLayer layer];

maskWithHole.frame = self.mask.layer.bounds;


UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[maskPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(maskWithHole.frame), CGRectGetMinY(maskWithHole.frame))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(maskWithHole.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(maskWithHole.frame))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(maskWithHole.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(maskWithHole.frame))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(maskWithHole.frame), CGRectGetMinY(maskWithHole.frame))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(maskWithHole.frame), CGRectGetMinY(maskWithHole.frame))];

[maskPath appendPath:myBezierPath];

[maskWithHole setPath:[maskPath CGPath]];
[maskWithHole setFillRule:kCAFillRuleEvenOdd];
[maskWithHole setFillColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];

self.mask.layer.mask = maskWithHole;

self.mask.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

On all Devices /iOS Versions there was no Problem expect for the new iPad Air, it has massive flickering in the masked area. Did Apple change something due to 64bit Architecture?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like we are seeing the same thing with only iPad Air and only with a test flight build.  We are trying to repo with a tethered build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug in iOS 7.0 in 7.1 beta it is fixed.